How to make any key input move on from a prompt?
I want to make a trivia game, but I want the game to start by the user pressing any key instead of a specific key. Here is the way it is now, and they have to press's' to continue, but I want it to be any key press.
start = input(f'''
Welcome to the quiz {name}
Please press s to continue. ''')
score = 0
if start == 's':
    print('Lets Go')

I haven't tried anything yet, and I haven't found the answer myself on here or any other platform.

This is one of the more commonly asked questions here.  There are system-dependent ways to do it, but the keyboard module is one of the easier ways.
